# Including simple PHP code into Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

How do I make this work? I've googled and even saw some examples here on Stackoverflow which show this kind of coding, but it doesn't work for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var infoClass = "";
  infoClass = <?php echo('test'); ?>;
  alert(infoClass);
</script>
```

The alert box displays empty box.

Comment: Look at the resulting JavaScript code and you will see what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your resulting JS code will be:

```
infoClass = test;
```

As there's no variable `test`, this won't work right. You need to wrap it in quotes, just like any other string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var infoClass = "";
  infoClass = '<?php echo('test'); ?>';
  alert(infoClass);
</script>
```

You can also use `json_encode()`, which may be handy for more complicated situations where you're echoing out arrays, objects, etc.:

```
infoClass = <?php echo json_encode('test'); ?>;
```

Comment: I've just tried both of these and in both cases the alert box displays "<?php echo('test'); ?>" instead of just test.

Comment: Sounds like PHP isn't enabled on your server, or that your file isn't named with a `.php` extension.

Comment: yep, it was in a .js file. Changed the extension to .php and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Why were you using `<script>` tags in a .js file, though?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your code is in a .php file, or inside a file that has an extension that will be parsed by PHP.

Also make sure the printed content will be inside of a string ( "" )